# Taxonomy archive template not working

Tags: custom-taxonomy, functions

I have a custom taxonomy (Talks)

I create for custom taxonomy `taxonomy-talks.php` its working on my localhost. When I upload FTP  still call `archive.php` or `taxonomy.php`. It must call `taxonomy-talks.php`but not working.

How can I fix it?

My Taxonomy Code:

```
register_taxonomy('Talks',array (
  0 => 'videolar',
),array( 'hierarchical' => true, 
         'label' => 'talks',
         'show_ui' => true,
         'query_var' => true,
         'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'talks')) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a taxonomy name `Talks`, this must be lowecase (`talks`).

If you look at the [`register_taxonomy()` Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/register_taxonomy) the following parameter description is shown:

```
<?php register_taxonomy( $taxonomy, $object_type, $args ); ?>
```

> **$taxonomy**
>   (string) *(required)* The name of the taxonomy. Name should be in *slug* form (must not contain capital letters or spaces) and not more than 32 characters long (database structure restriction).

Comment: Thank you @MikeMadern.I changed it but still don't working.

Comment: I don't know if it works, but did you refresh your permalink structure?

Comment: Yes i refresh right now still not working this is very interesting.